# Adding reply to comment system

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is add reply on each comment to my comment system but I don't know how to go about it could someone show or explain to me how to go about adding this.

Here is my comments database table.

```
id
user_id
target_id
comment
date_added
ip
type
```

And here is the function I am using

```
public function addMovieComment($movieid, $comment, $user_id, $ip){
    $comment = stripslashes(strip_tags($comment));
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
    $ip = stripslashes(strip_tags($ip));
    $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);
    if (!($e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE target_id='{$movieid}' AND user_id='{$user_id}' AND comment='{$comment}' AND type=2 AND ip='{$ip}'"))) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($e) == 0) {
         if (!($e = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(target_id,user_id,comment,date_added,type,ip) VALUES('{$movieid}','{$user_id}','{$comment}',NOW(),2,'{$ip}')"))) {
            exit(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

public function getMovieComments($movieid){
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    if (!($e = mysql_query("SELECT comments.*,users.username, users.avatar FROM comments,users WHERE comments.user_id=users.id AND comments.type=2 AND comments.target_id={$movieid} ORDER BY comments.id DESC"))) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    $comments = array();
    while (mysql_num_rows($e) && ($s = mysql_fetch_array($e))) {
        extract($s);
        $comments[$id]               = array();
        $comments[$id]['comment']    = stripslashes($comment);
        $comments[$id]['user_id']    = $user_id;
        $comments[$id]['username']   = $username;
        $comments[$id]['date_added'] = $date_added;
        $comments[$id]['avatar']     = $avatar;
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

And here is how I call the function to add and get the comments.

```
if ((@$comment) && (@$addcomment) && (@$_SESSION['loggeduser_id'] && (@$ip))){
    $comm->addMovieComment($mov['id'],$comment,$_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],$ip);
}

$comments = $comm->getMovieComments($mov['id']);
if (!count($comments)){ $comments = ''; $commentcount = 0; } else { $commentcount = count($comments); } 
$smarty->assign("comments",$comments);
$smarty->assign("commentcount",$commentcount);

if ($commentcount==1){
   $smarty->assign("comment_title",$commentcount." comment");
} else {
   $smarty->assign("comment_title",$commentcount." comments");
}
```

How can I go about adding this?

Comment: Why not use disqus or another well-developed comment system instead of trying to develop your own?

Comment: a reply is just another comment that happens to have a "parent". add a "reply_to" field in your comment table and point it at the record that the new "comment" is a reply for.

Comment: sometimes you like the challenge of being hard core and doing it yourself maybe? :-)

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but some hints and tips.

Presumably your Movies are articles about movies, and it may help to think of comments attached to a more generic object than something as specific as a movie.

Firstly it will help enormously if you start thinking of comments and articles as objects, so you need a Comment class and an Article class. If you're good, you can create a CommentView and ArticleView class which will effectively be the View class for the models represented down below.

Your Comment class will need an add and remove methods, plus some others. Similarly with Articles.

Your system should also have a User class, along with a set of rights which users may or may not have.

Get a pen and paper and think about how all these objects are going to interact and what they'll need in terms of database storage.

Think about separating the Controller (how the system processes requests from the user) from the Model (how the system is represented as objects/ stored in the database) and the View (how the various items are displayed.

Translating this into reality, you should by all means have an Controller::addComment() routine which validates your incoming data, and creates a new Comment. The Comment constructor should contain the SQL to create the object in the database.